# My damageReductionAmmounts is crashing Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

This is the error I am getting

```
[m[1;31m[11:33:51] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ja.FMLModContainer/]: Exception caught during firing event: null
    Index: 1
    Listeners:
        0: NORMAL
        1: ASM: class com.carbon.main_carbon$RegistryEvents registerItems(Lnet/minecraftforge/event/RegistryEvent$Register;)V
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.carbon.lists.ArmorMaterialList.getDamageReductionAmount(ArmorMaterialList.java:39)
    at net.minecraft.item.ArmorItem.<init>(ArmorItem.java:61)
    at com.carbon.main_carbon$RegistryEvents.registerItems(main_carbon.java:95)
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.ASMEventHandler_0_RegistryEvents_registerItems_Register.invoke(.dynamic)
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:80)
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:258)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLModContainer.fireEvent(FMLModContainer.java:106)
    at java.util.function.Consumer.lambda$andThen$0(Consumer.java:65)
    at java.util.function.Consumer.lambda$andThen$0(Consumer.java:65)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModContainer.transitionState(ModContainer.java:112)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModList.lambda$dispatchSynchronousEvent$5(ModList.java:125)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModList.dispatchSynchronousEvent(ModList.java:125)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModList.lambda$static$1(ModList.java:96)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.LifecycleEventProvider.dispatch(LifecycleEventProvider.java:71)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.dispatchAndHandleError(ModLoader.java:197)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.lambda$gatherAndInitializeMods$24(ModLoader.java:189)
    at net.minecraftforge.registries.GameData.fireRegistryEvents(GameData.java:969)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.gatherAndInitializeMods(ModLoader.java:189)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.ClientModLoader.lambda$begin$2(ClientModLoader.java:97)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.ClientModLoader.lambda$createRunnableWithCatch$5(ClientModLoader.java:113)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.ClientModLoader.begin(ClientModLoader.java:97)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:393)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.java:55)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:81)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65)
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:101)

[m[1;31m[11:33:51] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ja.FMLModContainer/LOADING]: Caught exception during event RegistryEvent.Register<minecraft:item> dispatch for modid carbon_fiber
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.carbon.lists.ArmorMaterialList.getDamageReductionAmount(ArmorMaterialList.java:39) ~[main/:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.item.ArmorItem.<init>(ArmorItem.java:61) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at com.carbon.main_carbon$RegistryEvents.registerItems(main_carbon.java:95) ~[main/:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.ASMEventHandler_0_RegistryEvents_registerItems_Register.invoke(.dynamic) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:80) ~[eventbus-2.0.0-milestone.1-service.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:258) ~[eventbus-2.0.0-milestone.1-service.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLModContainer.fireEvent(FMLModContainer.java:106) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:30.0] {re:classloading}
    at java.util.function.Consumer.lambda$andThen$0(Consumer.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.function.Consumer.lambda$andThen$0(Consumer.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModContainer.transitionState(ModContainer.java:112) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModList.lambda$dispatchSynchronousEvent$5(ModList.java:125) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModList.dispatchSynchronousEvent(ModList.java:125) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModList.lambda$static$1(ModList.java:96) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.LifecycleEventProvider.dispatch(LifecycleEventProvider.java:71) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.dispatchAndHandleError(ModLoader.java:197) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.lambda$gatherAndInitializeMods$24(ModLoader.java:189) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.registries.GameData.fireRegistryEvents(GameData.java:969) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.gatherAndInitializeMods(ModLoader.java:189) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.ClientModLoader.lambda$begin$2(ClientModLoader.java:97) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.ClientModLoader.lambda$createRunnableWithCatch$5(ClientModLoader.java:113) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.ClientModLoader.begin(ClientModLoader.java:97) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:393) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:140) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.java:55) ~[forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:81) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:101) [forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {}
[m[36m[11:33:51] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.FMLModContainer/LOADING]: Firing event for modid forge : RegistryEvent.Register<minecraft:item>
[m[36m[11:33:51] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.FMLModContainer/LOADING]: Fired event for modid forge : RegistryEvent.Register<minecraft:item>
[m[1;31m[11:33:51] [Render thread/FATAL] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/LOADING]: Failed to complete lifecycle event LOAD_REGISTRIES, 1 errors found
[m[1;31m[11:33:51] [Render thread/FATAL] [ne.mi.ev.EventBus/EVENTBUS]: EventBus 0 shutting down - future events will not be posted.
java.lang.Exception: stacktrace
```

This is my ArmorMaterialsList class

```
package com.carbon.lists;

import com.carbon.main_carbon;

import net.minecraft.inventory.EquipmentSlotType;
import net.minecraft.item.IArmorMaterial;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.crafting.Ingredient;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.util.SoundEvent;

public enum ArmorMaterialList implements IArmorMaterial {

    carbon("carbon_helmet", 1000, new int[] {8 ,10 ,9 ,7}, 20, ItemList.carbon_fiber_shard,      "entity.magma_cube.jump", 0.0f);

    private static final int[] max_damage_array = new int[] {13, 15, 16, 11};
    private String name, equipSound;
    private int duribility,enchantability;
    private int[] damageReductionAmmounts;
    private float toughness;
    private Item repairItem;

    private ArmorMaterialList(String name, int duribility, int[] damageReductionAmmounts, int enchantability, Item repairItem, String equipSound, float toughness) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getDurability(EquipmentSlotType slot) {
        return max_damage_array[slot.getIndex()] * this.duribility;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDamageReductionAmount(EquipmentSlotType slot) {
        return this.damageReductionAmmounts[slot.getIndex()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getEnchantability() {
        return this.enchantability;
    }

    @Override
    public SoundEvent getSoundEvent() {
        return new SoundEvent(new ResourceLocation(equipSound));
    }

    @Override
    public Ingredient getRepairMaterial() {
        return Ingredient.fromItems(this.repairItem);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return main_carbon.modid + ":" + this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public float getToughness() {
        return this.toughness;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private String name, equipSound;
    private int duribility,enchantability;
    private int[] damageReductionAmmounts;
    private float toughness;
    private Item repairItem;

    private ArmorMaterialList(String name, int duribility, int[] damageReductionAmmounts, int enchantability, Item repairItem, String equipSound, float toughness) {
    }
```

You have a bunch of fields, and you have a constructor that takes corresponding parameters, but you don't ever set the fields from the parameters. You need to do `this.name = name;`, etc. inside of the constructor body.